# Can i use roughness map with obj model?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am new to Three.js.
I have a *.obj model and normal, albedo, emissive and roughness maps. I tried to set maps with this code:

```
const orbObj = useLoader(OBJLoader, 'orb/orb.obj');

const [orb_albedo, orb_emissive, orb_normal, orb_roughness] = useLoader(TextureLoader, [
    'orb/orb_albedo.png',
    'orb/orb_emissive.png',
    'orb/orb_normal.png',
    'orb/orb_roughness.png',
  ]);

orbObj.traverse(function (node) {
    if (node instanceof Mesh) {
      node.material.map = orb_albedo;
      node.material.emissiveMap = orb_emissive;
      node.material.normalMap = orb_normal;
    }
});
```

But there is not roughnessMap property in the orbObj. So how can i use roughness map?

Comment: MeshStandardMaterial seems to have roughnessMap property.
https://threejs.org/docs/?q=meshstan#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.roughnessMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using MeshStandardMaterial:

```
import { MeshStandardMaterial } from 'three';

//...

orbObj.traverse(function (node) {
    if (node instanceof Mesh) {
      node.material = new MeshStandardMaterial();
      node.material.map = orb_albedo;
      node.material.emissiveMap = orb_emissive;
      node.material.normalMap = orb_normal;
      node.material.roughnessMap = orb_roughness;
    }
  });
```